# Force.com IDE v31.0 - Can't save to Server, only locally with Warning "Force.com sync state"

Tags: apex, ide, eclipse

Using plugin version 31.0.0.201406301722 on eclipse 4.4.0.v20140606-1558 it was perfectly usable for about a week... it was even fast with toolingAPI

Starting of today, I can't save anymore to Salesforce Servers. **At all.**

Just got the warning "File saved locally, not to server" and Type "Force.com sync state"

What I tried so far:

- doesn't help to refresh from Server.
- doesn't help to delete (hard irreversible form disk) and recreate the project
- doesn't help to create totally new project on different org / pods
- doesn't help to turn off ToolingAPI in the configuration

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you right click on the project & select 'Work Online'?

Comment: Thanks @DavinC - I did not check this, but I assume you are right. What actually helped was the following: 1.) uninstall the plugin. 2.) install version 30.x 3.) upgraded to version 31.x again - now it works like before. If I toggle now Work Offline/Online I can reproduce the odd behavior (which for sure is a feature). But how it may come, that it had toggled itself? I'm sure as hell I didn't swapped to Work Offline...

Comment: I haven't looked into it in depth but I think it defaults to 'Work Offline' for new projects since the latest release of the IDE.

Comment: No it was an old project in may case and it was Online a few minutes ago... And all projects where affected. Not only one. Seems that this IDE version has toggled it on it's own... very strange. New projects become spun up as "Online" now. Can't reproduce it.

Comment: That is strange, but at least it's resolved for you now ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @DavinC stated, make sure that you right-click on your Project > Force.com > **Work Online** not **Offline**

It seems that this setting may toggle without you have done it willingly. In my case it was an old existing project which form one minute to the other stopped working.